# displaying information in video in javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a videoplayer in javascript with different buttons. Now I want to add an object to my javascript that will give information about how the video is playing. If it's playing, if it's paused or if it's playing in slowmotion for example.

My code looks like this:

```
var doThings = function (n) { 'use strict';

    if (n === 1) {
        document.getElementById('video').play();
    }

    if (n === 2) {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
    }
};
var volume = function (n) { 'use strict';

    if (n === 1) {
        document.getElementById('video').muted = true;
    }

    if (n === 2) {
        document.getElementById('video').muted = false;
    }
};
var fullscreen = function() { 'use strict'; if (video.requestFullscreen) { video.requestFullscreen();

    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
};
var slowmotion = function (n) { 'use strict';

    if (n === 1) {
        document.getElementById('video').playbackRate = 0.5;
    }
};
var normalspeed = function(n) { 'use strict';

    if (n === 1) {
        document.getElementById('video').playbackRate = 1;
    }
};
```

I want to add an object that will indicate which function of the mediaplayer is currently being used. I could just use a console.log() but I would like the information to be displayed in the window in which the movie is playing.

Comment: You know you can just add the `use strict` to the entire scope.

Comment: How? What do you mean?

Comment: You can use a modal, alert or whatever your imagination can come up with. It isn't clear from your question what (exactly) you want to do.

Comment: i want a textbox to pop up once you clicked one of the buttons of the mediaplayer, but still be able to watch the video.

Comment: Stick 'use strict' once at the top of the script. No need to repeat it in each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="Display"></div>
```

Javascript in each function:

```
document.getElementById("Display").innerHTML("Function Being Used");
```

use CSS to position and style the element wherever you want, including on top of the video. Not sure the layout of your specific use case, but you can adjust the z-index and stack order to position the div anywhere in relation to your video.

May not work in full screen mode.